# Not able to create FirefoxDriver instance in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I had created a java application for selenium webdriver.

```
FirefoxDriver driverff= new FirefoxDriver();
```

used to create a new Firefox instance.
This is working fine.

I want to create a `java web application` to do the same.

I have embeded the same code in the `servlet` class in the `doget()` method and it throws

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver
```

Can someone tell me how i can fix this?

From an end to end perspective, what oi want to achieve is that a web page (done using servlets) has some buttons which when clicked need to open a selenium web driver and run the selenium scripts. I am assuming the java application for web-driver can be called using servlet.

If there is some other alternative to achieve this, please do suggest.

Comment: I don't have experience with Servlets, although I do know Selenium. Looking at [this](http://nitinpurswani.blogspot.in/2010/06/selenium-webdriver-running-remotely.html) link it appears you need to do something different in order to run Selenium within a servlet. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that Java can't find the class in question. Make sure it's on the classpath of your web app.

That said, you may run into problems later: Linux web servers often don't have an attached display so no X server is running. That will make it hard to start a browser :-) If that's the case for you, look up Google for "selenium xvnc" or "selenium headless"

Comment: What i want overall is a UI which when clicked runs webdriver application in backend. I thought servlet will help me in achieving this. Is the error because the two servers(Tomcat and Selenium) clash?

Comment: No, the error is solely because you didn't add the selenium JAR neither to your web apps nor to Tomcat's classpath.